# Default file watchers in Goland

Tags: go, file-watcher, goland

Is there a way to enable certain file watchers by default in all projects? It bugs me that I have to do this manually, but I've not found an option.

For example, I like to enable the `goimports` file watcher for every project in Goland.

Comment: the default shorcut for formatting is ctrl+alt+l in all jetbrains idea's

Comment: @Pizzalord Thanks for the comment; I think my original question was too formatting focused. I've clarified that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is now! They allow you to change the level of the file watcher. Simply  navigate to Preferences -> Tools -> File Watchers and on "level" select "Global".

This will, by default, add these File Watchers for other projects but it will not be enabled. To enable, simply check the "Enabled" box and you are good to go!

[File Watchers Global Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0reL.png)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment this is not possible. Follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12478 for updates.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
main menu -> File  -> Other Settings -> Settings for New Projects